# EC2 EBS drive letter assignment - is it as consistent as UI/API implies?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

In EC2 EBS, when I attach a device via UI or api, I specify the device name (eg /dev/sdf through sdp). That drive letter is consistent between reboots ? It seems implied that it is (otherwise why would they let me set it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually mean you are just rebooting the server then yes, the device name will remain. This is because you do the attach to the instance, and during a reboot everything about the instance stays the same. (Even data on the non-persistent instance disk.)

If on the other hand what you mean by "reboot" is you terminate the instance, and restart the AMI as a new instance, then technically the answer is no - but you can just re-attach the EBS drive to the instance, and use the same device name, so the effect is the same.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to reboot.